# How to free all nodes of my tree?

Tags: c, recursion, tree

I am trying to free a big tree in C. Each can have 12 sons. But when I execute this code, no node is deleted, my computer become slow, and it ends after 2-3 minutes on a seg fault

```
void freeTheNodes(node_t *n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
        if (n->children[i] != NULL) {
            freeTheNodes(n->children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(n);
}
```

Have you an idea about why my code don't work ?

Comment: Why did you write like this `if(n->children[i] != NULL)freeTheNodes(n->children[i]);`? Is your screen too small? The segmentation fault is probably caused by a *stack overflow*!

Comment: What is the exact error message you get. Have you tried running it in valgrind or gdb?

Comment: BTW: you don't need to check if the pointer you want to free is NULL. `free(NULL)` is OK and it won't actually do anything.

Comment: @MichaelWalz but you do need to check it's not null before trying to read `n->children`

Comment: @slim you mean to check if `n` is NULL ? Well that depends on the rest of the program, if the caller of `freeTheNodes` already ensures that `n` is not NULL, it would be useless to check it again. My comment is only based on the code we see in the question.

Comment: Okay, I find my problem : I didn't touched the code since a (long) time, and I forgot something : the next nodes have 12-1 nodes, and the next one 11-1. Please excuse my stupidity

Comment: @MichaelWalt It's recursive. `freeTheNodes()` is the caller of `freeTheNodes()` (except once) and the value of `n` changes each time (read from an element of `children`).

Answer (score 4):

You say each node can have 12 children, but you are trying to delete 13. This probably accounts for some of your problems.

It may also be the case that your tree is corrupt in the first place -- we can't tell because you haven't provided that code.

Your code assumes that `children` is not null -- make sure this applies.

I would have been tempted to instead write it as:

```
void freeTheNodes(node_t *n)
{
    if(n != NULL) {
       for (int i = 0; i < CHILD_COUNT; ++i) {
          freeTheNodes(n->children[i]);
       }
       free(n);
    }
}
```

... just because it's slightly simpler (at the cost of recursing one level deeper).

Step through your running code in a debugger, seeing whether it does what you expect, and examining the actual variables' actual content.

It's a good idea to use a tool like `electricfence` too, which causes your program to fail immediately if it tries to read/write outside allocated memory. I suspect that with `electricfence` your program would error quickly, rather than run for minutes before failing.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i)
```

will free for 13 nodes. Change it to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
```

Comment: Also mention, that `if (n->children[i]  !=  NULL)` is undefined behavior so it could explain the "*unexplicable*" observed behavior.